# Summation equation for products

Tags: summation

So if you want to add up all of the numbers from 1 to 100, the equation is fairly simple:
$ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}  $

Does a similar equation exist for multiplying every number from 1 to 100 together?

Comment: $n!$ grows much more quickly than any polynomial, see [Sterling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: Should have said;  it's a question of what you mean by an equation.   You can express such products in terms of the Gamma function, but that doesn't help much.  Mostly, people fall back on good approximations.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is factorial, and it grows even faster than an exponential.  There is no short formula for such a huge number.